# Make Background Have a Margin from Top of Page

Tags: css

I've tried

```
background-position:100px 0 0 0;
```

The CSS is curently

```
background: white url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat top fixed center;
```

I'm trying to get the [background inline](http://glamourunderground.com) with the top of the image.

Thank you,

Tara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-position` property works differently from something like `margin` or `padding`. Instead of declaring all four sides, you only declare two values: where it is horizontally, and where it is vertically. So in your case, you'd probably want something like this:

```
background:white url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat left 100px;
```

By default, it assumes that you're starting from the top, left corner. So `left 100px` is saying, "Keep it on the left, but go 100px down from the top." You can even use negative values. [More info on `background-position`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position)

Comment: almost right, it needs to read 'center' not 'left', but thank you!